# In Microsoft SQL or Tableau, how to find the overlapping time of the data?

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

I am working on a project in school and it requires me to find the actual downtime of all the machines within the production line.

Attached is the picture of the overlapping time and the desired output I want. Is there any way that I can find the actual downtime by excluding the overlapping data in Microsoft MSQL or Tableau?

The actual downtime = Total downtime - overlapping downtime. Thank you!

[Original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdt2l.jpg)

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxYKJ.jpg)

Comment: Add data in text format instead of an Image and mention expected output as well.

Comment: Let's think about this. First, you should have provided expected output (in a consumable format). It appears that your sample has a single overlap - the first 2 rows. Correct? Is the logic here based on multiple rows having the same value for TimeStarted? Or is it more complicated? Don't make assumptions based on looking at a few rows - that can be very misleading. You might want to search for "gaps and islands" since this might be a simple version of that commonly used logic.

Answer (score 0):

The code below looks for entries with overlaps and chops the overlaps down into discrete time blocks.  The union removes duplicate time blocks.   With this code the answer is 24955 seconds of downtime.

```
create table #t1 (TimeStarted datetime, TimeCompleted datetime, id integer)
insert into #t1 values ('20180416 12 am', '20180416 2:02:21am', 1211958)
...
;
with overlap_cte
as
(
select a.*, 
   case when b.timestarted >= a.timestarted then b.timestarted else a.timestarted end as overlapstart, 
   case when b.timecompleted <= a.timecompleted then b.timecompleted else a.timecompleted end as overlapend
from #t1 a
   inner join #t1 b on (b.timestarted between a.timestarted and a.timecompleted or b.timecompleted between a.timestarted and a.timecompleted) and a.id <> b.id
),
unique_downtime_cte
as
(
select timestarted, overlapstart as timecompleted from overlap_cte where timestarted <> overlapstart
union
select overlapend, timecompleted from overlap_cte where overlapend <> timecompleted
union
select overlapstart, overlapend from overlap_cte
union
select timestarted, timecompleted from #t1 where id not in (select id from overlap_cte)
)
select *, datediff(ss, timestarted, timecompleted) as downtime_seconds from unique_downtime_cte
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. What if I want my result to be displayed in his way. How can I do it? https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxYKJ.jpg

Comment: @Felix, you'll need to add a Machine column and extend the JOIN condition to "... and a.id <> b.id AND a.machine = b.machine."  Also add Machine to every SELECT in the UNIONs.  Production Line is probably from a related table for Machine - join with that to get Production Line.   Query already gives TimeStarted, TimeCompleted.   You can calculate Downtime (Hours) with DATEDIFF, as shown in query - change ss to hh (hrs).   Note, however, that downtimes may not be contiguous, so you can have >1 row for every machine.   Not sure what the last column is - it's probably out of topic.